# Can I plot several histograms in 3d?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I'd like to plot several histograms similar to the way [these](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html)bar graphs are plotted.  I've tried using the arrays returned by `hist`, but it seems that the bin edges are returned, so I can't use them in `bar`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use `np.histogram` to pre-compute the histogram, as you found you'll get the `hist` array and the bin *edges*. `plt.bar` expects the bin centres, so calculate them with:

```
xs = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2
```

To adapt the Matplotlib example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
nbins = 50
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
    ys = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=10, size=2000)

    hist, bins = np.histogram(ys, bins=nbins)
    xs = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2

    ax.bar(xs, hist, zs=z, zdir='y', color=c, ec=c, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]